# Java call objects by there name and use them

Tags: java

I am wondering how I can change my objects individually when giving them a name (setName) seen below.

Code:

```
//textfield & labels
    String[] arrLabelsKlanten = new String[] {"KlantID", "Gebruikersnaam", "Wachtwoord", "Voornaam", "Achternaam", "Straat", "Huisnummer", "Gemeente", "Email", "Telefoonnr"};
    for (int i = 0; i < arrLabelsKlanten.length; i++)
    {
        if(i < 5)
        {
            lblLabelsKlanten = new ClassLabels.lblIngelogdAls(arrLabelsKlanten[i] + ":", 350, 510 + i * 50, 300, 50);
            lblLabelsKlanten.setName(String.valueOf(i));
            add(lblLabelsKlanten);

            txtTextvakken = new ClassTextfields.txtAdmin(500, 515 + i * 50, 300, 30);
            txtTextvakken.setName(String.valueOf(i));
            add(txtTextvakken);
        }else if (i >= 5)
        {
            lblLabelsKlanten = new ClassLabels.lblIngelogdAls(arrLabelsKlanten[i] + ":", 910, 260 + i * 50, 300, 50);
            lblLabelsKlanten.setName(String.valueOf(i));
            add(lblLabelsKlanten);

            txtTextvakken = new ClassTextfields.txtAdmin(1050, 265 + i * 50, 300, 30);
            txtTextvakken.setName(String.valueOf(i));
            add(txtTextvakken);
        }   
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your strings are stored in an array named `lblLabelKlanten`, the `valueOf(i)` is your iterator, not the array.

`lblLabelKlanten.setName(arrLabalKlanten[i]);` should get you the String inside your array, and set the name of your object to the string value.

at least I think that is the question you are asking?

Comment: First of all thank you for your comment, but no that was not what I meant... What I meant was, now everything works the textfield gets the string from the array and stuff but actually the name of the textfield is my iterator, so it can be 0,1,2,3,... for each textfield. My question now is how can I make it so for example textfield 3 is not enabled anymore?